# Assembler calling conventions for Windows 10 API routines

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86-64, masm, calling-convention

Back in the 1970's I cut my teeth on the IBM 370 mainframe assembler, and in the early 1980's I had the original IBM PC, with the Microsoft Macro Assembler. At that time it was sold as a separate product, and came with a very useful manual. Now I'm retired, in quarantine, and looking to get back into assembler language.

I downloaded Visual Studio 2019 Community, which has MASM included in it, and for interactive debugging I'm using x64dbg. My PC is 64 bit, so I'm using the ML64 assembler as provided with VS.

---

My question is regarding the calling convention for the Windows API functions.

These days the Windows functions all seem to be geared toward C++ and, in my understanding, the calling convention reflects the machine code that is generated by C++ for calling those functions. I want to develop a template that I can use for all future calls, so it's coded for a nonexistent function called apifunc. This fictional function has five parameters.

```
; command to assemble is: 
; ml64 samplecall.asm /link /subsystem:windows /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /entry:Start
extrn ExitProcess:   PROC 
extrn apifunc:       PROC ; any hypothetical api function with five parameters
.data
;
parm1         dword ?     ; these could be any required data type
parm2         dword ?   
parm3         dword ? 
parm4         dword ? 
parm5         dword ? 
;
.code
Start PROC
;
  sub    rsp, 32          ; room on the stack for first four parameters, 8 bytes each
;
  lea    rcx, parm1       ; pass the first four parameters in registers
  lea    rdx, parm2
  lea    r8,  parm3
  lea    r9,  parm4
  lea    rax, parm5       ; address of the fifth and last parameter
  push   rax              ; put it on the stack
  call   apifunc          ; call the hypothetical function
;
  call ExitProcess
;
Start ENDP
End:
```

Does this code look even remotely correct? When control returns from apifunc, do I have any indication at all of whether it was successful and, if it was not, why not? Do I need to add 40 back to the stack pointer in order to leave it in the same condition in which it was passed to me?

Please be patient with me, because I now stand at the bottom of a very steep learning curve. I hope my questions make sense, and that I provided enough information.

Comment: Remotely correct, yes. Really correct, no :) For starters, the arguments may not be pointers. Also, you put the 5th argument in the wrong place. It should be on top of the shadow space. Yes, you need to free the stack space you allocated (unless you terminate the process like in your example). What functions return is documented for each one separately.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention is a rough description. Yes the caller (not callee) pops any stack args (and the shadow space). Unless you just `call ExitProcess`, then of course no need to `add rsp,32` / `sub rsp,32` between calls. (Stack args go *above* the shadow space, and RSP must be aligned by 16 before a call.  Thus also the first stack arg is aligned).  I'd recommend looking at compiler asm output for examples, e.g. https://godbolt.org/ has x64 MSVC available. Also https://www.agner.org/optimize/ has a good calling convention guide

Comment: Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019

Comment: You also need to declare unwind codes to describe your stack layout in order for stack walking to work.

Comment: *"When control returns from apifunc, do I have any indication at all of whether it was successful and, if it was not, why not?"* - The documentation for each API call includes information about its error reporting. API's commonly indicate error/success through the return value, with `GetLastError` usually providing additional error information. COM calls return a single `HRESULT` value that encodes all sorts of information, e.g. an error/success indicator in the MSB (bit 31).

Comment: Manual preparation of Fastcall arguments and of stack alignment is rather tedious, that's why macros were invented for. You may look how my implementation of Windows ABI invokation is expanded in this example: https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/winabi.htm#WinABI

Comment: What I need to get straight is the stack usage in function calls. I'll state my understanding, and maybe others can correct it. The first four parameters go in registers, but space is allocated for them on the stack anyway, so for 64 bit that would be SUB RSP,32. However, if there is a fifth argument, it goes at the top of the stack rather than after the four empty slots. So if the address of the fifth parameter is in RAX, then that would be PUSH RAX, and this instruction should appear before the SUB RSP,32. Is that right so far?

Comment: "Top of the stack" does not usually have the meaning you use. Since x86 stack grows down the "top of the stack" (the last pushed item) actually has the lowest address. That is why you need to push the 5th argument first so that the arguments are in increasing memory addresses. What you should remember is that you want the arguments in order, low to high addresses. How you achieve that is up to you. You could `sub rsp, 40` and then `mov [rsp+32], arg5` and get rid of the whole LIFO stack mess.

Comment: What about this approach just to make it more intuitive: Load RAX with address of the 5th argument, and push it. Then set RAX to zero and push it four times, for arguments 1 through 4. If there were a 6th argument, it would be pushed before the 5th, and so on for any number of arguments. In other words, the arguments are pushed in reverse order, starting with the last one, but first 4 are always zero because they are actually passed in registers instead. Would that follow the calling convention?

Comment: Yes, but arguments are not necessarily pointers. Also the values in the shadow space don't matter, don't have to be zero.

Comment: Yes, I understand that in some contexts RAX could be loaded with a value rather than an address for argument 5, and setting the shadow space to zero is just for clarity, especially when doing interactive debugging.

Comment: I think I got carried away with my simplistic example, in which the program calls only one function that has parameters, and then exits. If, more normally, the program calls multiple functions, then I assume that the same shadow area of the stack is reused for all of them. Is that right, or is the shadow area reallocated on the stack for each function call? If the same shadow area is reused for further calls, then it seems to imply that the call parameters starting with the 5th have been popped off the stack by the called function, but the shadow area has been left intact for further use.

Comment: No, the caller manages the stack space for all arguments. You can reuse the shadow space even if something else is above it (there is always something else above it :))

Comment: Here's my confusion: Say I call a function with 5 parameters. At the time of the call, the shadow space is at the top of the stack, corresponding to the 4 parameters that are passed in registers, and the 5th parameter is immediately below. Fine, everything as expected. The function does its own processing, calling other routines, who knows, and when control returns to me, the stack pointer has been decremented a few more times. Now I call a different function, also with 5 parameters. Do I start all over, decrementing the stack pointer by 40, and placing the new 5th parameter at the end again?

Comment: Unless I do start over, how can the second called function ever find its 5th parameter? It's this aspect of serial reusability of the stack for function calls that still eludes me.

Comment: You can reuse the same area if you don't mess with the stack pointer. If you do and you have stuff there you want preserved you should indeed redo the whole thing. When writing a function you can usually determine a static layout based on the total amount of locals and the largest outgoing parameter list so you adjust the stack pointer once in the prologue and reuse the shadow space and extra argument memory.